# accounts.createUser doesn't work on production server

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

i integrated a create user using `Accounts.createUser` method with meteor 1.3 with mongoDB 2.6 and it was working. After updating to meteor 1.4 and mongoDB to 3.2. the create user stop working on production server. although i tested it on the local server and it was running but not on production mode.

```
Accounts:createUser({
    userName: userName,
    email: email,
    lastName: lastName,
    type: type,
    firstName: firstName,
    password: password,
    profile:{   
            registerDate: new Date(),
            birthDate: birthDate,
            gender: gender,
            phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
            }
    }, function(Error)
    {
      if(Error) {
                console.log(Error);
                }
      if(!Error) {
                // send a verification link
                 }
});
```

i also tried to set the `Accounts.onCreateUser` on the server side to make sure the function retern the new user. but i still get the same error

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(option, user){
 user.profile = { 
                 registerDate :  option.profile.registerDate,
                 birthDate: option.profile.phoneNumber,
                 gender: option.profile.phoneNumber,
                 phoneNumber: option.profile.phoneNumber,
               };
 console.log(user);
 return user;
 });
```

Related accounts packages:

```
accounts-password                  1.3.4
accounts-ui                        1.1.9
```

this is the error that i am getting

> error 500
>
> errorType "Meteor.Error"
>
> message "Internal server error [500]"
>
> reason "Internal server error"
>
> ```
>    "r.makeErrorType/n@http://www.giggorilla.co.uk/ab20b773d706000be869bec1f69baea22bf74af4.js?meteor_js_resource=true:3:3462
>    ._livedata_result@http://www.giggorilla.co.uk/ab20b773d706000be869bec1f69baea22bf74af4.js?meteor_js_resource=true:57:21601
>    o/o@http://www.giggorilla.co.uk/ab20b773d706000be869bec1f69baea22bf74af4.js?meteor_js_resource=true:57:6983
>    ._launchConnection/t.socket.onmessage/<@http://www.giggorilla.co.uk/ab20b773d706000be869bec1f69baea22bf74af4.js?meteor_js_resource=true:57:606
>    A.forEach@http://www.giggorilla.co.uk/ab20b773d706000be869bec1f69baea22bf74af4.js?meteor_js_resource=true:1:863
>    ._launchConnection/t.socket.onmessage@http://www.giggorilla.co.uk/ab20b773d706000be869bec1f69baea22bf74af4.js?meteor_js_resource=true:57:562
>    g</r.prototype.dispatchEvent@http://www.giggorilla.co.uk/ab20b773d706000be869bec1f69baea22bf74af4.js?meteor_js_resource=true:56:1171
>    g</C.prototype._dispatchMessage@http://www.giggorilla.co.uk/ab20b773d706000be869bec1f69baea22bf74af4.js?meteor_js_resource=true:56:14765
>    g</C.prototype._didMessage@http://www.giggorilla.co.uk/ab20b773d706000be869bec1f69baea22bf74af4.js?meteor_js_resource=true:56:15655
>    g</C.websocket/o.ws.onmessage@http://www.giggorilla.co.uk/ab20b773d706000be869bec1f69baea22bf74af4.js?meteor_js_resource=true:56:17755
> ```

Comment: how do you connect your app to mongo db on your prod server? Does maybe the user not exist in your 3.2 database or has not the correct rights?

Comment: @Jankapunkt i am using a local mongodb locally. in fact i installed mongo package, so the url is mongodb:127.0.0.1:3000/meteor. i can see on the console that  the user is created but it can't auto login. i've tried to use `accounts.createUser` on the server side and i get the user id. and once is returned i call `accounts.loginWithPassword` still the same problem. But after creating the user i can login with the new user credentials. Just the autologin doesn't work.